# Как улучшить данную функцию под неограниченное количество пар "ключ" - "значение"

Tags: kotlin

```
fun getMap(z: MutableList<String>): MutableMap<String, String> {
      return mutableMapOf(
        z[0] to readLine().toString(),
        z[1] to readLine().toString(),
        z[2] to readLine().toString(),
        z[3] to readLine().toString(),
        z[4] to readLine().toString()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вынести вот это

```
    z[0] to readLine().toString(),
    z[1] to readLine().toString(),
    z[2] to readLine().toString(),
    z[3] to readLine().toString(),
    z[4] to readLine().toString()
```

в цикл. Примерно так

```
for (idx in 0..z.size) {
    z[idx] to readLine() // readLine() уже строка, зачем еще раз конвертировать-то?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getMap(z: List<String>): Map<String, String> {
    return z.associateWith { readln() }
}
```